# How Can the DOS Utility Strings 2.5 be Used in DOSBOX?

Tags: string, batch-file, dos, dosbox

Having just learned that DOSBOX is incompatible with BATCH files that contain user inputs defined with the "set /p" command, I went to do some digging and found that DOSBOX allows for variable-based user input if the STRINGS utility is installed.

Unfortunately, I'm unaware of how exactly to install Strings 2.5 so that DOSBOX recognizes it as a valid command when I run a BATCH file that uses Strings 2.5 features.

How can DOS utilities be installed when using DOSBOX rather than the OS itself?

Additionally, if I were to give this program to someone, would they need the Strings 2.5 utility installed as well?

The utility I'm using is one published in PC Magazine back in 92 I believe. [link](http://info.wsisiz.edu.pl/~bse26236/batutil/help/STRINGS.HTM)
[download on FTP](ftp://ftp.pl.freebsd.org/pub/msdos/coast/batutil/string25.zip)

---

Thanks,

~ Jason

Comment: The only Strings utility I know of is this one: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/strings.aspx and it does not accept user input like the `SET /P` command does.

Comment: The utility I'm using is one published in PC Magazine back in 92 I believe.  Link: http://info.wsisiz.edu.pl/~bse26236/batutil/help/STRINGS.HTM

Comment: once downloaded (question edited to show link), just `mount C C:\downloads` to get access to computer directory called `C:\downloads` where you unzipped `strings25.zip`. You have now access to `strings`

Comment: I wouldn't recommend trying to write batch scripts under DOSBox. It's only designed to run games, and its batch capabilities are limited to whatever MS-DOS games actually used.